# Бот не видит библиотеки и отказывается запускаться на удалённом сервере

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Сначала консоль выдаёт, что версия Python не поддерживает aiogram. После переключения на более новую версию консоль выдает, что модуля aiogram вовсе нет. Пытался решить эту проблему разными способами, но ничего не помогло.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не осуждаю но что там по хентаю?)) Сделайте предварительно `pip install aiogram` и лучше даже в виртуальном окружении

Comment: Но pip3 list показывает что библиотека aiogram уже установлена